# Is there a way to know how "busy" someone's machine is from a browser's JS?

Tags: javascript, performance, cpu, user-experience

If my page's JS has an obnoxiously long and computationally heavy operation, is there a quick and dirty way to know if they are AFK with no apps on or if they're mining bitcoin in 1000 threads?

In other words, is there a way to roughly gauge how "busy" a CPU is via JavaScript?

I'm referencing code that is being run by an extension.

I was thinking about running a hashing loop for a a few hundred milliseconds and get a report on how long it took, however this doesn't take into account background processes, overall CPU power, et cetera.

Comment: No. What problem are you trying to solve?

Comment: It's kind of hard to explain - it involves a client who will absolutely refuse to refactor

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> I'm referencing code that is being run by an extension.

If you by extension mean **WebExtension** there is the [Idle API](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/Add-ons/WebExtensions/API/idle)<sup>*</sup> you can use to [`queryState()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/Add-ons/WebExtensions/API/idle/queryState). However, the [IdleState](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/Add-ons/WebExtensions/API/idle/IdleState) result can only return the states "active", "idle" or "locked".

The latter two should be useful though.

<sub>*) The API is not fully supported in Edge at this moment.</sub>

Answer (score 1):

You can't gauge CPU usage or any other resources directly with javascript.

Though I don't understand the reason for your question, you can create a server-side application to measure your resources such as RAM and etc. then try to create a web service with resource output. Now you can use AJAX call in a client loop to find out your resource usage.